# Why are Greek letters not displayed in the R-Shiny plot title with the 'expression' command?

Tags: shiny, expression, symbols

**Greek letters not displayed in R-Shiny using the command expression**

The following R-code works locally and the alpha is properly displayed in the title of the plot:

```
require(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId="Plot")))
server <- function(input, output, session){
output$Plot <- renderPlot({plot(0, 0, main=expression(alpha))})
# }
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

But on the shiny-server there appears no alpha at all. I do not use ggplot only base-R.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works using the unicodes for the greek leters, in case of \alpha = \u03b1

```
require(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId="Plot")))
server <- function(input, output, session){
output$Plot <- renderPlot({plot(0, 0, main="\u03b1")})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```